# Git diff ignores textconv when provided paths

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-diff

I have set up my git diff that when it is called on a binary file, it will use a custom program as textconv which is specified in the .gitconfig file. That will look like this

```
[diff "file"]
    textconv = python "'/path/to/program.py'"
    xfuncname = .*name=.*
[core]
    attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes
```

and in the .gitattributes file I have

```
*.file diff=file
```

This works fine if applied to my git repo and in a terminal. However, my company uses TortoiseGit as front end for git, which brings its own diff tools that i couldn't bring to work with a textconv option. Instead for viewing a diff I supplied a command like

```
cmd /K git diff %base %mine
```

The output will then be

```
diff --git "a/path/in/repo.file" "b/temporary/path/out/of/repo.file"
index e4ab82c..3c0f4d7 100644
Binary files "a/path/in/repo.file" and "b/temporary/path/out/of/repo.file" differ
```

Usually git would apply textconv to the binary files and will work without problem if instead of "%base", "HEAD" is provided. I suspect that git runs as if it was called with --no-index and ignores the .gitattributes file and therefore does not now that is has to apply the textconv.

Is there a way to get around that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force the textconv conversion with the `--textconv` option:

```
cmd /K git diff --textconv %base %mine
```

Comment: I did not know diff had this option. Thank you, that solved my problem!